# Find the points of intersection of the following pairs of lines

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

$\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3 \\-1 \\2\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\-1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\-2\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}2 \\0 \\3\end{bmatrix}$

My solution:

Eliminating $\begin{bmatrix}x \\y \\z\end{bmatrix}$ gives $\begin{bmatrix}3 \\-1 \\2\end{bmatrix} + t\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\-2\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}2 \\0 \\3\end{bmatrix}$. Equating coefficients gives three equations for s and t:

$3 + t = 1 + 2s$

$-1 + t = 1$

$2 - t = -2 + 3s$

This is where I get stuck. I was expecting $s$ and $t$ to be in separate equations so I can simply solve it and then plug it in the original equation but I'm confused on how to go about this point.

Comment: it must be $$-1+t=1$$

Comment: Move all s and t terms to the left side, and all the constants on the right side. You now have a linear system of equations that can be solved for s and t using gauss-jordan elimination.

Comment: Oh i see then i take t = 2 and plug it in either the first or 3rd equation for s?

Comment: both of them. They have to give the same $s$, else the two lines don't meet.

Comment: in your last equation it should be $2-t = -2 +3s$

Comment: @michael so since the first equation gives 2 for s and the 3rd gives 2/3, there is no point of intersections?

Comment: I think so, but how did you get the $ 2+ t = -2 +3s$? In this case it would work

Comment: @michael it was a typo, i just edited it.

Comment: A word of advice: you don't need to surround _each and every vector_ with dollars: surround the whole equation with a single pair of dollars. Also, using column vectors in inline equations looks terrible.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be that you did not expect to get more equations than variables.

Just pick to easy ones to determine $s$ and $t$ and then check if the third equation holds as well for these values. Otherwise there is no solution.

The easiest one is the middle one, it gives $t = 2$.
Then the first gives $s = 2$ and the third gives $s = 2/3$. 
Or: the third equation would turn into $0 = 4$, so it is not fulfilled.

This means there is no solution to the problem. There is no intersection.

[image: 3D scene]

([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS66v.jpg))

Answer (score 1):

First, let us take "known terms" to one side and $t$ and $s$ terms to the other, and rewrite your equation as:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -2 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3 \\-1 \\2\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\-2\end{bmatrix} = - t\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\-1\end{bmatrix} + s\begin{bmatrix}2 \\0 \\3\end{bmatrix}$$

Translate that to a system:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
-t+2s=2 \\
-t=-2 \\
t+3s=4
\end{array}\right.$$

So $t=2$, and plugging in we get $-2+2s=2$ and $2+3s=4$, so $s=0$, but that does not satisfy the second equation, so there is no solution. It seems those two lines do not intersect. Being not parallel, they must belong to distinct planes in space. Or I have made a calculation mistake. If so, please point it out :).